# Possible pregnancy in dogs

Tags: dogs

My 2yrs 6month old yellow lab was in heat 3/4 weeks ago. I also have her brother from same litter. I did ever6i could to watch them but am worried that he got to her towards end of season. She appears to be putting on weight. Question is there any way I can check if she is pregnant and if so best course of action.

Comment: you can use a pregnancy test made for people or one made for dogs,just follow the instructions on the test.